# Finding number of elements in one vector that are less than an element in another vector

Tags: r, sorting, vector, time-complexity, ranking

Say we have a couple vectors

```
a <- c(1, 2, 2, 4, 7)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
```

For each element `b[i]` in `b` I want find the number of elements in `a` that's less than `b[i]`, or, equivalent, I want to know the rank of b_i in `c(b[i], a)`.

there are a couple naive ways I can think of, e.g. doing either of the following `length(b)` times:

```
min_rank(c(b[i], a))
sum(a < b[i])
```

What's the best way to do this if `length(a)` = `length(b)` = N where N is large?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I'm wondering if there's a more computationally efficient way to do this, i.e. if I can do better than quadratic time in this case.

Vectorization is always cool though ;), thanks @Henrik!

**Running time**

```
a <- rpois(100000, 20)
b <- rpois(100000, 10)

system.time(
  result1 <- sapply(b, function(x) sum(a < x))
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 71.15    0.00   71.16

sw <- proc.time()
  bu <- sort(unique(b))
  ab <- sort(c(a, bu))
  ind <- match(bu, ab)
  nbelow <- ind - 1:length(bu)
  result2 <- sapply(b, function(x) nbelow[match(x, bu)])
proc.time() - sw

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.46    0.00    0.48 

sw <- proc.time()
  a1 <- sort(a)
  result3 <- findInterval(b - sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), a1)
proc.time() - sw

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.00    0.00    0.03 

identical(result1, result2) && identical(result2, result3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1 for providing a tiny, easily reproducible toy data set, and code you have tried. To make it even easier for people that wish help you to check that their code produces the correct result, please also post your desired output. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `a` is weakly sorted increasingly, use `findInterval`:

```
a <- sort(a)
## gives points less than or equal to b[i]
findInterval(b, a)
# [1] 1 3 3 4 5
## to do strictly less than, subtract a small bit from b
## uses .Machine$double.eps (the smallest distinguishable difference)
findInterval(b - sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), a)
# [1] 0 1 3 4 4
```

Comment: Never new of that function, so thanks!  Wish it was in the _see also_ section of `?match`

Comment: @GavinKelly It is in the *See Also* section, along with `pmatch`, `charmatch`, and `match.arg`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're really optimising this process for large N, then you may want to remove duplicate values in `b` at least initially, and then you can sort and match:

```
bu <- sort(unique(b))
ab <- sort(c(a, bu))
ind <- match(bu, ab)
nbelow <- ind - 1:length(bu)
```

As we've merged a and b values into ab, the `match` includes all a less than the specific value of b together with all b's, so that's why we remove the cummulative count of b on the final line.  I suspect this may be faster for large sets - it should be if `match` is internally optimised for sorted lists, which one would hope to be the case.  It should then be a trivial matter to map back `nbelow` to your original set of `b`s

Comment: +1: this solution relies on a (quick)sort - that is, the overall complexity is in n*log(n) instead of n².

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim this is "the best way", but it's *a* way. `sapply` applies the (anonymous) `function` to each element of `b`.

```
 sapply(b, function(x) sum(a < x))
 # [1] 0 1 3 4 4
```