# Counting number of elements for each vector in a dataframe on larger than each element in vector 2 in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

[Finding number of elements in one vector that are less than an element in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942710/finding-number-of-elements-in-one-vector-that-are-less-than-an-element-in-anothe)

This post has a very similar question, now `b` is a dataframe instead of a vecor. How do we do the same comparison if `a` has different length than each vecor in `b`?

```
 sapply(b, function(x) sum(a < x))
```

Comment: maybe explain a bit more? and then refer the similarity to someone else's question?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  The answer to the question you cited is not dependent on the length of `a` or `b` so you could just use a one of the `apply` functions on your `b` data frame.  Also, I am not sure what you mean when you say that "a has different length than each vecor[sic] in b".  If `b` is a data frame, all of its elements have the same length, so while it may be different than the length of `a` they will be the same length as each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but:

If `a` is a scalar, then this same `sapply` statement returns the number of elements that are larger than `a` in each column. If `a` is a vector, you may be interested in `sapply(b, function(x) sum(max(a) < x))`, to count the number of elements in each column of `b` that are greater than all the elements in `a`.