# Count values in a vector less than each one of the elements in another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have two vectors `r` and `d` and I'd like to know the number of times `r<d(i)` where `i=1:length(d)`.

```
r=rand(1,1E7);
d=linspace(0,1,10);
```

So far I've got the following, but it's not very elegant:

```
for i=1:length(d)
sum(r<d(i))
end
```

This is an example in R but I'm not really sure this would work for matlab:
[Finding number of elements in one vector that are less than an element in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942710/finding-number-of-elements-in-one-vector-that-are-less-than-an-element-in-anothe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use singleton expansion with [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html): faster, more elegant than the loop, but also more memory-intensive:

```
result = sum(bsxfun(@lt, r(:), d(:).'), 1);
```

In recent Matlab versions `bsxfun` can be dropped thanks to [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
result = sum(r(:)<d(:).', 1);
```

An alternative approach is to use the [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) function with the `'cumcount'` option:

```
result = histcounts(r(:), [-inf; d(:); inf], 'Normalization', 'cumcount');
result = result(1:end-1);
```

Comment: @Brice ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ :-D

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! The first one works for me with the example vectors but my actual r is 1E7 in length.... whereas d is only 10. It says i will run out of memory. Shall I update my question to reflect this. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HCAI The `histcounts` approach should be better then

Comment: Thank you very much, I'd like to accept your answer. The histcount is super fast!!!

Answer (score 3):

You may build a matrix flagging values from vector `r` inferior to values from vector `d` in one time with `bsxfun`, then sum the values:

```
flag=bsxfun(@lt,r',d);
result=sum(flag,1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'd like to accept Luis' as the histcount seems to be quite a bit quicker although this also works.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in `d`, count how many times this element is bigger than the elements in `r`, which is equivalent to your problem.

```
r=rand(1,10);
d=linspace(0,1,10);

result = sum(d>r(:))
```

Output:

```
result =
     0     0     1     2     7     8     8     8     9    10
```